# How a wandering Passenger can be depicted in a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, random, runnable

I am writing a multi-threaded program in which Passenger wanders for a random time and waits for a cab ride. I am wondering how do I depict a wandering passenger in the Passenger Thread?

```
class Passenger extends ThreadEvent implements Runnable
{
    String passengerStatus;
    Integer passengerNumber;

    public  String getPassengerStatus() {
        return passengerStatus;
    }

    public  void setPassengerStatus(String status) {
        passengerStatus = status;
    }


    public Passenger(Integer _passengerNumber) {
        passengerNumber = _passengerNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Passenger wandering ");
            // How to Implement wandering passenger here?
            System.out.println("Passenger waiting for Ride ");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Comment: How about putting the thread to sleep for a random time?

Comment: @yts This might sound silly but How do I make it wait for the cab ride then if its sleeping? I Am sorry my skills on Thread area are so poor.

Comment: It won't. It will do it when it wakes up. The sleep will make the code pause there for a little (only in that thread) and then when it wakes up it will continue. Try a Thread.sleep(1000) and see what happens ;)